# how to pick put a specific row in matlab with the largest amount of numbers above a certain value

Tags: matlab

so I have an array in matlab with 61 rows and 181 columns. I want to find the row or column with the largest amount of numbers above a certain value and then count those numbers. Some guidance would be great.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Say your matrix is `M`

First lets create a new matrix `MThresh` which will indicate which number is greater than a threshold `thresh`

```
MThresh = M>Thresh;
```

Now, in order to know which row has the most of them we just need to sum all of the columns (`MThresh` contains `1` where it is larger and `0` where it is not).

```
N = sum(MThresh,2);
```

This is a column vector. Now we just have to find the maximum. The row is what we want here.

```
[Howmany Row] = max(N);
```

You can do it all in a single line of code:

```
[Howmany Row] = max(sum(M>Thresh,2));
```